# the command - 'npx create-react-app myapp' does not work

Tags: javascript, node.js, npm, npx

the following command throws the following error
command = npx create-react-app my-app
error =
'"node"' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
operable program or batch file.

before you say create node as an environment variable - it has been created,
node works perfectly fine, npm works perfectly fine - just calling npx raises this issue

[image: npm, npx, node versions]

[image]

any idea why?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

fixed the issue by running the command on command prompt and not using hyper terminal
think it has issues running maybe windows based commands on linux

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).